# Using a single servlet object instantiation for all request

Tags: servlets

On my web app I have a class with an object that will handle all requests of a certain kind. The web app is a clinic management system and each time a patient comes I would like the patient, P object, to manipulated by the single instantiation of the object. The object that needs to be single is my patient queue manager, QM. If I happen to have an instantiation of the QM for each each patient the server will be flooded with QM objects and also patients will actually not be on the same queue.I will appreciate any ideas about which utilities I will have to use to ensure the existence of only one QM object when the application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), or create a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), instantiate your QueueManager in this listener and [store it as an attribute of the servlet context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), and then [retrieve it from there](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) each time you need it.

Or use a dependency injection framework like Spring or CDI that will create the singleton for you and inject it where you need it.